# How to animate the expansion of a UICollectionViewCell's content upon selection?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

I'm trying to reproduce into my own app the animation that occurs when you select a cell in the App Store's Today section. Here's how it looks:

[image: The App Store selection animation]

The difficulty here is that the views that make the content of the cell seems to be moving from the cell to another `UIViewController` *(detail)* while being animated in the process. I guess it has something to do with *custom segue animators*.
How would you write this animator object, and what are the needed steps to perform on the collection view cell and the detail view controller? (using only UIKit and CoreAnimation)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Lots of articles and resources about this exact topic online: https://medium.com/@eric.dockery283/custom-view-transitions-like-the-new-app-store-a2a1181229b6

Comment: Thank you! This post surely highlights the solution. I'm going to give it a try right now. 

Comment: Glad to help, you should have a look around through before posting on here as this question would be considered too broad for this site. just for future reference

Answer (score 4):

There is an elegant transition library for iOS like app store animation named HERO.

[image]
 
Please check following link.

https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero